# Fill a rectangle with triangles

Tags: combinatorics

In a plane with a Cartesian coordinate system, we call a segment tame if it is parallel to one of the two coordinate axes and has an integer distance from it, otherwise we name it wild.
Let m and n be odd positive integers. The rectangle with the corner points (0,0), (m, 0), (m, n) and
(0, n) is covered with a finite number of triangles without gaps and without overlapping. The set of these triangles
be M. The following conditions are met:

(1) Every triangle in M ​​has at least one tame side.

(2) For each tame side of a triangle in M, the corresponding height has the length 1.

(3) Every wild side of a triangle from M is a common side of exactly two triangles from M.

Proof: At least two triangles in M ​​have two tame sides each.

No idea how to solve that, can somenody help?

Comment: What is the source of this question, please?

Comment: 1) Have you attempted to produce such a triangulation ? 2) Please answer Gerry Myerson.

Comment: Its was a question in a competition for maths in germany. I tried also for solving all, but couldn´t solve that. And as the deadline is now over, I am asking for some hints or advices how to solve that elegantly.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's from https://www.mathe-wettbewerbe.de/fileadmin/Mathe-Wettbewerbe/Bundeswettbewerb_Mathematik/Dokumente/Aufgaben_und_Loesungen_BWM/aufgaben_21_2.pdf which, as far as I can tell was finished yesterday. The watermark across the page itself says "Confidential until September 1st". It was also discussed in the comments under [this deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237452/every-number-k-has-a-multiple-of-the-form-10a-10b-for-these-numbers-dn) yesterday.